# Suddenly can't type non english characters any more

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, special-characters

Suddenly my Kubuntu 16.04 refuses to write some characters.

Usually I was able to press <kbd>´</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> = `á` but now I just get `´a` on some applications like Firefox on some other applications like Konsole or Dolphin the accent isn't even displayed and only the `a` appears.

The single exception is LibreOffice where the input is working as expected.

I've wiped out my single keyboard input method configuration in `System preferences > Input > Keyboard > Layout` and configured it up again, also have consulted [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438499/cant-type-non-english-characters-in-certain-places) question, but to no avail.

These are the contents of my `locale`:

```
$ locale
LANG=es_MX.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_MX:es
LC_CTYPE="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_MX.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This is the output of `$ im-config -m`

```
default
ibus
none

none
```

Comment: This probably didn't happen "suddenly". Any package installed/removed recently, for example?

Comment: You may be totally correct, yesterday I added the Kubuntu Backports repository to fix the buggy `muon-discover` app and updated my system the usual way from the icon in the task bar.

Comment: [Bug #1573755](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1573755) comes to mind. Can you please run the command `im-config -m` and let us know the output by editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have IBus set as the input method framework without having IBus installed. I suggest that you run this command:

```
im-config -n none
```

and log out and log in again. Doing so might make a difference.

Comment: Like magic, it worked, thank you! Just out of curiosity, do you know what may have happened?

Comment: @eridani: Nope. As you can see at that bug report, the root cause has not been spotted yet. Glad that I could help you. :)